# How to get number of rows from the another table which math to the first table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables in my database:

- `Films` (id, name)
- `Awards` (id, name)
- `Films_has_Awards` (film_id, awd_id)

How can I get the number of awards for each films?

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    Films.name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Films 
     JOIN Films_has_Awards ON Films_has_Awards.film_id = Films.id
     JOIN Awards ON Awards.id = Films_has_Awards.awd_id) AS NumberOfAwards
FROM 
    Films;
```

But I always get the same number of awards for each film.

Comment: actually,  use a group by. Cartesian joins are not very efficient. Essentially, you have a DIM and a FACT table. Use then like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine.  You need a *correlation* condition in the subquery:

```
SELECT f.name,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM Films_has_Awards fha
         WHERE fha.file_id = f.id
-----------------------------^ "correlates" to outer query
        ) AS NumberOfAwards
FROM Films f;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You don't need the awards table, presumably.  There is no filtering on the award type.
- You don't need `Films` in the subquery.

Comment: This also means EVERY ROW is a different query. So be careful how far and big you let such a query get.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Films.name, Count(*)
FROM Films
JOIN Films_has_Awards
ON Films_has_Awards.film_id = Films.id
Group by Films.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select f.id, min(f.name) name, count(*) awards
from films f join film_awards fa on f.id = fa.film_id
group by f.id
```